# POSTGRESQL: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 31: invalid start byte

Tags: sql, postgresql, encoding, utf-8

unfortunately, I´m quite a new user of PostgreSQL. I wanna please You for advice - I imported several data into created databases in PostgreSQL via FME. Created databases use UTF-8 encoding and I just want to backup my databases. But backup dialogue show me this message: **'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 31: invalid start byte**. Is possible to fix it please?

Thank You so much!

Comment: what encoding uses your client?..

Comment: UTF-8, but imported data are probably in WIN1250.

Comment: did you try to import data using utf8 client?..

Comment: Not yet. Importing data process takes more than 6 days, so I want to know, if I can use already imported data... Is there any possibility, how to safe these data?

Comment: to be frank, I don't know. I never tried to mix character sets since 9th oracle :) just export data with the client you want to use for import. And never met problems in Postgres - not sure what was main reason :)

Answer (score 2):

I am not saying you have the same problem, but I had exactly the same error when I configured the binary path wrong in pgAdmin.

*File / Preferences / Paths / Binary Paths / PostgreSQL Binary Path*: You need to add the path where pgDump.exe is.

Pretty annoying error message, lead me comlpetely wrong way...